# android profiler how to view call chart

Tags: android-studio, profiler

I must be overlooking something obvious, but I haven't figured out how to use the profiler that's part of Android Studio 3.5.

I have tried choosing "sample java methods" and "trace java methods" but don't see how to display the call stack progression and cpu times.

After starting the profiler, it appears that when I tap "+" and attach to my app, it immediately starts recording. The only stop button I see is the red one in the upper left area that stops the current profiling session. I've tried clicking that, which stops the time progressions in the main window. Then, I click on the CPU area and some headings appear below the graph area, including "call chart". Clicking on "call chart" does nothing and the rest of the screen is blank.

I also tried a slightly different approach. First, tap "+" to attach to my app. Then, click in the graph area. At that point, I get  "record" button. I click that and it changes to a stop button. After a short while, I click the "stop" button. The graph shows a shaded area which presumably corresponds to the samples between start and stop. But clicking in that area, or anywhere else, seems to have no effect.

What am I misssing ? Thanks.

Comment: Looking at some videos, it seems that the call chart should appear immediately when tapping "stop". Is there something wrong with my app configuration ?

Comment: it seems the studio couldn't capture any calls at all. You can try doing it one more time, but when the recording starts, do some process/UI interaction in your app.  then stop the recording. If it takes some time to load the recording that means it was able to capture some calls. wait for it to access `call chart`.

Comment: btw make sure that the device you are using has android API > 21.

Comment: On which device are you running your app (it must be debuggable)? 
Emulator? Physical device? 
Which API level?

Comment: Running on an LG G6, Android 9 (level 28). My build has min sdk 19, target sdk 28, and I'm compiling with 28.